# Why is this in-place assignment allocating more memory?

Tags: julia

I am trying to understand memory management a little better. I have the following example code:

```
begin 
    mutable struct SimplestStruct
        a::Float64
    end
    
    function SimplestLoop!(a::Array{SimplestStruct, 1}, x::Float64)
        for i in 1:length(a)
            @inbounds a[i].a = x
        end
    end
    
    simples = fill(SimplestStruct(rand()), 100)
    
    @time SimplestLoop!(simples, 6.0)
end
```

As far as I can work out from the docs + various good posts around about in-place operations, `SimplestLoop!` should operate on its first argument without allocating any extra memory. However, @time reports 17k allocations.

Is there an obvious reason why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please note that `simples` contains 100 times the same (not so) random value, which might not be what you wanted. Also, it is customary to use a snake_case naming convention for functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you perform the `@time` measurement several times, you'll see that the first measurement is different from the others. This is because you're actually mostly measuring (just-ahead-of-time) compilation time and memory allocations.

When the objective is to better understand runtime performance, it is generally recommended to use [`BenchmarkTools`](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) to perform the benchmarks:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime SimplestLoop!($simples, 6.0)
  82.930 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

BenchmarkTools's `@btime` macro takes care of handling compilation times, as well as averaging runtime measurements over a sufficiently large number of samples to get accurate estimations. With this, we see that there are indeed no allocations in your code, as expected.